# Why replication collapse but not stall leads to DNA break?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, dna-replication, dna-damage

I have been looking into the concept of replication dynamics and was wondering why collapsing but not stalling leads to a DNA break.

Comment: I recommend improving this post by explaining to us what "collapsing" and "stalling" mean. What context are you talking about? How do you know that collapsing but not stalling leads to a DNA break?

Answer (score 1):

*Stalling precedes collapsing. And collapsing precedes breaking.* Hence, both stalling and collapsing precede, and lead to, breaking; but not every stalling leads to collapsing, and not every collapsing leads to breaking.